# Month in simple date formatter always return JANUARY

Tags: java, date, simpledateformat

I convert string to date by using simple date format but the month of the date is always return JANUARY here's my code:

```
  public static void main(String args[]){

    String date = "2017-12-29";
    SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-mm-dd");
    SimpleDateFormat dateFormatter = new SimpleDateFormat("MMMM dd, YYYY");
    try {
        Date startEntryDate = formatter.parse(date);
        System.out.println(dateFormatter.format(startEntryDate));

    } catch (ParseException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: It should be MM instead of mm

Comment: Lower case 'm' is for minutes, upper case 'm' is for month.
Please see the doc for SimpleDateFormat: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html

Comment: Slightly aside, why are you struggling with the old, outdated and simultaneously notoriously troublesome `SimpleDateFormat` class? [`java.time`, the modern Java date and time API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/), is so much nicer to work with.

Answer (score 2):

Try to use

`new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");`

`mm` means minutes.
`MM` - months.

```
Letter   Date or Time Component   Presentation       Examples
G        Era designator             Text                AD
y        Year                       Year                1996;    96
M        Month in year              Month               July; Jul; 07
w        Week in year               Number               27
W        Week in month              Number               2
D        Day in year                Number               189
d        Day in month               Number               10
F        Day of week in month       Number               2
E        Day in week                Text               Tuesday; Tue
a        Am/pm marker               Text               PM
H        Hour in day (0-23)         Number               0
k        Hour in day (1-24)         Number               24
K        Hour in am/pm (0-11)       Number               0
h        Hour in am/pm (1-12)       Number               12
m        Minute in hour             Number               30
s        Second in minute           Number               55
S        Millisecond                Number               978
z        Time zone                  General time zone   Pacific Standard Time; PST; GMT-08:00
Z        Time zone                  RFC 822 time zone   -0800
```

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned already you have to use `MM` instead of `mm`, but?
Why not using [`java.time`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) library :

```
String month = LocalDate.parse("2017-12-29").getMonth().name();
```

Comment: @OleV.V. check the [the ideone demo](https://ideone.com/bjcwKx) name come from [Enum class](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/Month.html)

Comment: Ah, [`Enum.name()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/lang/Enum.html#name--), of course, my bad.

Comment: Exactly @OleV.V.

Comment: And the great news is, of course, that in this case the 1-arg `LocalDate.parse()` frees us from using an explicit formatter for parsing at all. Since it appears to be very easy to get those formatters wrong, this is more valuable than one might think at first.

Comment: This is correct @OleV.V. :)

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
SimpleDateFormat dateFormatter = new SimpleDateFormat("MMMM dd, yyyy");
```

Answer (score 0):

```
   Try this:

        new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy")
        MM is "month" (not mm)
        dd is "day" (not DD)
        It's all in the javadoc for SimpleDateFormat


        FYI, the reason your format is still a valid date format is that:

        mm is "minutes"
        DD is "day in year"
        Also, you don't need the cast to Date... it already is a Date (or it 
        explodes):

            public static void main(String[] args) throws ParseException {
         System.out.println(new 
            SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy").parse("08/16/2011"));
            }
        Output:
```

Tue Aug 16 00:00:00 EST 2011

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
    String date = "2017-8-28";
    SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
    SimpleDateFormat dateFormatter = new SimpleDateFormat("MMMM dd, YYYY");
    try {
        Date startEntryDate = formatter.parse(date);
        System.out.println(dateFormatter.format(startEntryDate));

    } catch (ParseException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Comment: Code-only answers are very seldom helpful. Please explain the change you have made compared to the OP’s code and in particular: how it helps,